# Java Regexp to Match ASCII Characters

Tags: java, regex

What regex would match any ASCII character in java?

I've already tried:

```
^[\\p{ASCII}]*$
```

but found that it didn't match lots of things that I wanted (like spaces, parentheses, etc...). I'm hoping to avoid explicitly listing all 127 ASCII characters in a format like:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^*(),.<>~`[]{}\\/+=-\\s]*$
```

Comment: This question doesn't indicate if you just require a single character (in the body) or multiple characters (in the title).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have never used `\\p{ASCII}` but I have used  `^[\\u0000-\\u007F]*$`

Comment: Should there really be two slashes before the u ? i.e. isn't `^[\u0000-\u007F]*$` correct?

Comment: I tried, single slash works as well. Normally you need double slash because it's an escape command.

By the way, I had problems with an String because it has chars from the extended ASCII, but `\\p{ASCII}` is only the standard. For extended ASCII you can use `^[\\u0000-\\u00FE]*$` (`FE` instead of `7F`)

Comment: Why FE, and not FF?

Answer (score 34):

The first try was almost correct

```
"^\\p{ASCII}*$"
```

Comment: Although I would use `"^\\p{ASCII}+$"` so as to not match the empty string, but that might be philosophical... :)

Answer (score 2):

If you only want the printable ASCII characters you can use `^[ -~]*$` - i.e. all characters between space and tilde.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_code_chart

Answer (score 1):

For JavaScript it'll be `/^[\x00-\x7F]*$/.test('blah')`

Answer (score 0):

I think question about getting ASCII characters from a raw string which has both ASCII and special characters...

```
public String getOnlyASCII(String raw) {
    Pattern asciiPattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{ASCII}*$");
    Matcher matcher = asciiPattern.matcher(raw);
    String asciiString = null;
    if (matcher.find()) {
        asciiString = matcher.group();
    }
    return asciiString;
}
```

The above program will remove the non ascii string and return the string. Thanks to @Oleg Pavliv for pattern.

For ex:

raw = ��+919986774157

asciiString = +919986774157