# ASCII char check using regex(java)

Tags: java, regex, ascii

I have a string like     `message = "ASDF rfghy  !@#$ :>< "`

I want to check this string contain ASCII value between 0 to 255 using regex(java).

Comment: Note that ASCII doesn't *have* values over 127.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Regexp to Match ASCII Characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071236/java-regexp-to-match-ascii-characters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this code to do this check:

```
System.out.println("Matches: " + message.matches("[\u0000-\u00FF]+"));
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try the regex:

```
"^\\p{ASCII}*$"
```

Answer (score 3):

In regex, `\x00` matches the hex character `00` and character classes work on these. So you can do:

```
/^[\x00-\x7F]+$/
```

to match a string of one or more ascii values.