# Allow ascii character during jsf regex validation

Tags: java, regex, email, jsf, validation

I have this code to validate an email address and I think it works fine for normal circumstances

```xhtml
<h:inputText id="email" value="#{myBean.email}"
        required="true">
    <f:validateRegex pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}" />
</h:inputText>
```

But if somebody enters this sample email

```
lòmbardi.Çorneliö@mymail.com
```

..the regex fails.

Question, is there a way to have a validator allows other ascii characters?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071236/java-regexp-to-match-ascii-characters

Comment: You might also want to allow lòmbardi.Çorneliö@[παράδειγμα.δοκιμή](http://παράδειγμα.δοκιμή), lòmbardi.Çorneliö@subdomain.mymail.com, etc.

Comment: ahh yes...that seems logical now.. so I am thinking more on this matter...any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't validate only latin characters in `A-Z` range. This makes [since May 2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) no sense anymore as practically any unicode character is allowed in domain name. It's much better to validate only the occurrence of the `@` and `.` characters.

```html
<f:validateRegex pattern="([^.@]+)(\.[^.@]+)*@([^.@]+\.)+([^.@]+)" />
```

#### See also:

- [Email validation using regular expression in JSF 2 / PrimeFaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875108/email-validation-using-regular-expression-in-jsf-2-primefaces/12824163#12824163)